# What is the range of Symmetra's Sentry Turret?

Tags: overwatch

When playing against Symmetra I find myself killed by the turrets quite often, but when I try to use them to control a space myself I always mis-judge and leave them stranded out-of-range, to be easily picked off. They can notify me that a player is in the area, but never do much damage.

What is the range of the Sentry Turrets spawned by Symmetra? Are they only useful as very close-range traps/sensors, or do they have enough range to control a medium-sized space as well?

Comment: If nobody else answers this, I plan to eventually take some screenshots to clarify exactly what kind of range these have.

Comment: Dragonrages answer is good but if you could provide screenshots they would also be very helpful!

Comment: @JeremyBanks I noticed you unaccepted my answer, could you explain why?

Answer (score 5):

According [to the wiki](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Sentry_Turret), which seems to be supported on [this experiment by Reddit user mctiggs](https://reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/48axy7/hero_ability_ranges/):

> Symmetra places a small turret that fires a laser at targets within 10
>   meters

[image: Turrets]
*(image source: above reddit post)*

Comment: How far is 10 meters?  We need something to compare this to, like Symmatra's camera height.  Or just a picture would work.

Comment: Reinhardt is approximately 2.23 meters tall, so a bit less than 4.5x Reinhardt's height. @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft

Comment: I've played Symmetra for hours, and I feel like that's an overestimate. The effective range is more like 10 *feet*.

Comment: @DCShannon when i get home from work, I will run tests to confirm this.

Comment: It is unfortunate that [the wiki editor did not include a source/reference](http://overwatch.wikia.com/index.php?title=Sentry_Turret&diff=8903&oldid=8051).

Comment: [It looks like someone did tests with screenshots here](https://reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/48axy7/hero_ability_ranges/). We may want to reference that Reddit post as a primary source, instead of referencing the wiki.

Comment: @JeremyBanks added in the source. thanks for finding that

Comment: Well then I guess I'll start acting like they can shoot further than I've been, and see what kind of results I get.